# How I can filter Tortoise SVN revision graph before opening it?

Tags: tortoisesvn

Is there a way to filter the Tortoise SVN revision graph before you open it? Its taking over a minute to open it, which is leading to too many hallway swordfights. I can filter it easily after its open, but thats my problem.

Ideally, I really only need to see the last 100 or so revisions, not everything since the dawn of time.

Comment: LOL, you only haave to wait a minute? My TSVN client is telling me it expects to take an hour.

Comment: I'm in everyone else's boat, this would prove incredibly useful, especially in my case where I know I need to closely examine the last 4 revisions. Analogous experience with limiting the number of log messages displayed would make it very natural to limit the number of revisions one retrieves going back from the current version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot filter the graph - the TortoiseSVN documentation says:

> In order to generate the graph, TortoiseSVN must fetch all log messages from the repository root. Needless to say this can take several minutes even with a repository of a few thousand revisions, depending on server speed, network bandwidth, etc. If you try this with something like the Apache project which currently has over 500,000 revisions you could be waiting for some time.
>
> The good news is that if you are using log caching, you only have to suffer this delay once. After that, log data is held locally. Log caching is enabled in TortoiseSVN's settings.

So - make sure that log caching is enabled and future graph views will be faster.

Comment: Thanks, I just selected "Power User Defaults" for the log caching settings, and now my revision graph takes a split second to view.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible. Because to generate the graph, TSVN requires the info from the log of all revisions. Otherwise it could miss copies (e.g., if you create a tag from r2 to HEAD, with HEAD being r1000).