# is there any way to generate a revision graph for a portion of an SVN repository?

Tags: svn, version-control, revision-graph

We have a large SVN repository with about 70,000 revisions. I am working in a project which is a much smaller portion of the repository: in TortoiseSVN I viewed the log of the project trunk with "Stop on copy/rename" unchecked and "Include merge revisions" checked and there are only 83 revisions.

**Is there any way to get a revision graph of these 83 revisions, or any of the other 20-or-so revisions that have branched from the trunk?**

When I try to use TortoiseSVN it just stalls and tells me it will take an hour, because it has to look at the entire SVN repository log.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How I can filter Tortoise SVN revision graph before opening it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769446/how-i-can-filter-tortoise-svn-revision-graph-before-opening-it)

Comment: Create trunk-only|branches-only dumps and load into new fresh (updatable later, if needed ) repo?

Comment: That's a thought... I bit the bullet and just ran the revision graph during lunch. Now that I have a log cache it's fast. (And svn will show you only the revision graph relevant to a particular area in the repository. Unfortunately it bails on trying to show merges.)